# A Fuchsian Group?

Tags: geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

Let $p_k := e^{\pi/2 i k}$, $k \in \{0, 1,2,3\}$. Let $b_k$ the geodesic of the hyperbolic disk connecting $p_k$ and $p_{k+1(\text{mod}4)}$. For instance, $p_0$ and $p_1$ are connected by the lower left quarter-circle of center $(1+i)$ and radius 1.
Let $\alpha_k$ be the element in $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{D})$ that ''reflects'' along the geodesic $b_k$.
Let $G < \text{Aut}(\mathbb{D})$ be the subgroup generated by the $\alpha$'s. Is $G$ a Fuchsian Group?

Moreover, let $\beta_1 \in \text{Aut}(\mathbb{D})$ be the orientation-preserving transformation that sends $b_0$ to $b_1$ (keeping $p_1$ fixed) and $\beta_2 \in \text{Aut}(\mathbb{D})$ the (orientation-preserving) one that sends $b_2$ onto $b_3$ (keeping $p_3$ fixed). Define $H$ to be the group generated by the $\beta$'s. Is it a Fuchsian group?

I would be very grateful if someone could give me a ''graphical'' explanation of how the ''typical'' Fuchsian group looks like.

Comment: The more common definition for a Fuchsian group is a discrete subgroup of the **orientation-preserving** isometry group of the hyperbolic disk/plane. Is this the definition you use? There is also a definition which allows for orientation-reversing transformations, so if this is the one you use then you should say.

Comment: Good point. Yes, I use this broader definition of Fuchsian group.

Comment: Ok cool, could you also clarify then what the definition of $\beta_i$ is? There are two transformations satisfying those properties, one preserving orientation and one not.

Comment: @Daniel Rust: Edited. Thanks for pointing that out (actually, it already clarifies something in my head)

Comment: For your first question, I'm not too sure on the definition of Fuchsian group when you consider orientation reversing generating elements. For the second question, it helps to draw the geodesics in the upper half plane. You then have two vertical geodesics with two semicircular geodesics between them. $\beta_1$ can then be seen to be a translation and $\beta_2$ is a little more difficult to describe. The important point to note is that both have a single fixed point on the boundary and so are parabolic transformations.

Comment: I should mention that I'm identifying the point $(0,1)$ in the disk model with $\infty$ in the hyperbolic half plane model. Up to a possible change of coordinates this is the usual identification between the models.

Comment: To help with the intuition, The following picture should give an idea of the fundamental domain for the action of the group $\langle \beta_1,\beta_2\rangle$ (note that a change of coordinates will be able to move one of the hyperbolic squares in this image to the area bounded by your $b_i$s) http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/25/H2_tiling_24i-4.png/600px-H2_tiling_24i-4.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$H$ is a Fuchsian group in the classical sense. The main properties are:

- its elements are isometries of the hyperbolic plane
- the group is discrete, meaning the points of a single orbit won't come arbitrarily close to one another in the hyperbolic metric
- it preserves orientation

The group $G$ contains reflections, so it depends on the broader understanding of Fuchsian groups.

Since you asked for something “graphical”, here are your two groups visualized as subgroups of a given triangle reflection group, with triangles of the same orbit colored in the same color. The corners don't form the ideal square you described, but that's just a global Möbius transformation missing here, so no “real” difference.

[image: Group G]

[image: Group H]

Comment: Really helpful!